# Pip command - not found but there are similar ones

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I have Anaconda Navigator and am working with python through VS Code. When I try to use pip install keras, and pip install tensorflow in my terminal in VS Code, I get error messages that says "Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones".

I have attempted a few other commands, and uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda navigator.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download pip and put it in your path using 'Edit environment variables'

Answer (score 0):

well, if you are on conda navigador, don't even bother to do that. just select "no installed", filter with keras and install it right there. Much easier

Comment: There are a number of options under the not installed option. There is nothing that says pip though. What is the name of it?

Comment: You don't need pip. Conda will install it for you in your selected environment. Just select "Keras" and click the "apply" button. It will check all the dependencies and install it for you. If you you share a screenshot i might be able to help you better.